# Pre-fill modal from db (non-Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sqlite

I'm trying to pre-fill a form with values from a database (sqlite).

I've mocked up my code in JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/daikini/e71mvg7n/

There's also a catch here... I'm not using bootstrap, for various reasons. So, if it can be accomplished without it, that's the preference.

I've got a good db connection, I can pull and post (using PHP) . But, I haven't been able to figure out pulling it into the form just yet.

Here's my JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks again for the help on this. I'm still running into problems when I try to prefill the form (which is inside a modal) using PHP and Javascript. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row) 
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['job_id'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['job_title'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['date_create'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td><a href='#' id='editbtn". $row['job_id']."' class='edit-button' name='edit". $row['job_id']."' data-value='".json_encode($row, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."'>EDIT</a></td>";

if ($row['display']) {
    echo '<td><form method="post" action="update_jobs.php"><input type="checkbox" name="'. $row['job_id'] .  '" value="'. $row['display'] .'" checked />'; 
} else {
    echo '<td><form method="post" action="update_jobs.php"><input type="checkbox" name="'. $row['job_id'] .  '" value="'. $row['display'] .'" />'; 
    }

echo '<td class="last"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" ></form></td>';

echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo $row['position_summary'];

?>
```

and JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var editModal = document.getElementById('editModal');
var editbtn = document.getElementById("editbtn" + job_id).value;

jQuery('.edit-button').click(function() {
    id = jQuery(this).attr('data-abstract-id');
    });

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
editbtn.onclick = function() {
    var _data = $(this).data('value');
    editModal.style.display = 'block';

    console.log(_data);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#job-id').val(_data['job_id']);
        $('#date-created').val(_data['date_create']);
        $('#job_title').val(_data['job_title']);
        $('#position_summary').text(_data['position_summary']);
        $('#duty1').val(_data['duty1']);
        $('#duty2').val(_data['duty2']);
        $('#duty3').val(_data['duty3']);
        $('#duty4').val(_data['duty4']);
        $('#duty5').val(_data['duty5']);
        $('#duty6').val(_data['duty6']);
        $('#duty7').val(_data['duty7']);
        $('#duty8').val(_data['duty1']);
        $('#edu1').val(_data['edu1']);
        $('#edu2').val(_data['edu2']);
        $('#edu3').val(_data['edu3']);
        $('#edu4').val(_data['edu4']);
        $('#edu5').val(_data['edu5']);
        $('#edu6').val(_data['edu6']);
        $('#edu7').val(_data['edu7']);
        $('#edu8').val(_data['edu8']);
    }, 500);


}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-close-edit-modal', function () {
editModal.style.display = 'none';
});


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target.id == 'editModal') {
    editModal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you want to fill the form with predefined values. If you want to load it at page load you can just generate the HTML with PHP and printing the data into the value="" tag of the desired inputs.

Or if you load the data by using ajax you can use jQuery to fill the elements value.

```
$("form input[name='job_title']").val(value);
```

If this is not what you want please clarify your question.

EDIT:

I'm gonna keep this short, still not 100% sure what you want to do.

But what I notice is that you load the JSON encoded data from the .edit-button data-value but that want to access it as an object. You should decode it first.

```
var _data = $.parseJSON($(this).data('value'));
```

Try to elaborate your question is it is still not working, what do you want to achieve and try to upload a working example somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Jordan! If I print into the value of the input tag, (i.e. value="<?php '$id' ?>" ) nothing get pulled in, which I'm sure means I'm overlooking something. I'd prefer the JQuery route, so when I do that, I need to assign it to an element by name (getElementsByName), correct?

Comment: I updated your Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e71mvg7n/1/) note the job_title input `<input type="text" name="job_title" placeholder="Job Title" value='Default value printed here'/>`

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't pulling the value in with the PHP script: It's displaying the rows of data from the table in a FOREACH loop. So, I needed to do: name=" . '$row['field_name']' . ">